# Limit execution only through localhost

Tags: php, localhost

This could be a kind of strange question. I have a php file in a public web site where I have access to the server. For the moment we do not need to set Cron job for this file execution. However I need to limit the execution of this file only via localhost. I don't have any precise idea about the way should I do this. Is there any way to detect whether the request is localhost or not? I mean with PHP. Or should I need to handle this via security setting or firewall of the server?

Comment: Do you control the server? I mean do you have access there via ssh?

Comment: $hostname = \`hostname\`; or add specific variable to the environ. You'll run script depending on presence of this variable in the environ

Comment: If you mean that you only want to be able to access the script from the server, simply move it out of your `public_html` folder.

Comment: Do you run it through the server or though the CLI?

Comment: The site is developed with Zend. Since I have configured virtualhost my URL is like expo.local:81/import/user. So would like to know how can I access this location via command line. Thanks.

Comment: @Prasad Rajapaksha look at DocumentRoot in httpd.conf for that virtualhost or at $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] calling php through the webserver. But, the directory might be an alias, so the best way is to put php script in that directory with echo dirname(_ _ FILE _ _); it will show you physical path to this directory. ps: remove spaces between _, _  and FILE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you want to be able to execute the script only from the server, and not via the web from another host. You have two options:

**Option 1**

move it out of the `public_html` folder. There is no reason you should not take this option, unless there is something preventing you from doing so. In that case,

**Option 2:**

Wrap the entire code in the following `if` statement

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli')
{
   //your code
}
```

Alternatively,

```
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli')
   die();

//your code
```

This ensures your script will only run if invoked from the command line, and not via the web.

Comment: The site is developed with Zend. Since I have configured virtualhost my URL is like http://expo.local:81/import/user. So would like to know how can I access this location via command line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could check IP addresses like this:

```
if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]!=$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"])
{ 
exit;
}
```